# MySQL database setup issue

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm setting up a database for a fantasy football league where the head honchos can enter their projections based on each player's stats and point values associated with those stats.

There are six player "groups":

```
QB
RB
WR
TE
K
DEF / ST
```

QB, RB, WR and TE groups all have the same stats options.
K has its own set of stats options
DEF / ST has its own set of stats options

My question is this:

Am I better of creating a single table (PROJECTIONS) and then making the positions, stats, etc... fields within that table OR should I have a separate table for each player group?

Which would be the best, most efficient way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single table is enough  for this scenario .... each group has same property,stats then why u create extra table ...

Comment: Each group does not have the same stats. QB, WR, RB, and TE all have the same stats, so I created a table called ff_offense and set up my fields for that group. I'm guessing I have to set up a table for K (kicker) and DEF / ST (defense / special teams) since each one has its own set of possible stats.

Comment: I agree with QueryMaster in the single table solution. Having a column for each of the possible stats across all groups, then when you populate the row, depending on which group is currently in question the non-used stats are null or 0.